# Netlify CMS - blog posts from BitBucket show on front end but not back end CMS

Tags: bitbucket, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I am having a problem using Netlify CMS with BitBucket.When I create a post in the CMS editor it saves correctly to the BitBucket repo,Netlify does a build and it publishes to Gatsby front-end without any problem.

However,when CMS is refreshed,none of the posts are visible,so cannot be edited without going into BitBucket and editing directly or pulling to local repo for editing and pushing again.Obviously this defeats the purpose of a CMS in the first place.

For reference I am using the Kaldi Gatsby/Netlify CMS starter the source code for which can be found [here](https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms).

Here is what I see in the CMS directly after a post is created.
[image]

But when the CMS page is refreshed the Blog list is empty despite the post saving to BitBucket and showing on front-end.
[image]

I have looked through the Gatsby code trying to find something which could be causing the posts not to display in the CMS,but cannot see anything.If anyone has any ideas where to look or why this is happening I'd be grateful for any help.Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Incidentally,the web pages included in the Kaldi template show up fine in the CMS.

[image]

I checked the console after trying to load the `blog` collection and it lists the error below for all the post markdown files.So it seems the CMS is trying to get them but can't for some reason.Unfortunately,the expanded view of the error doesn't offer any pointers to the source of the problem.

[image]

Thanks again for any assistance!

Comment: When do you see the above error?

Comment: Could this be a race condition? Or caching?

Comment: @ksav because the `Blog` collection is the default view in the CMS,the above console errors appear immediately after navigating to `/admin`.

Comment: @Chris The `page` collection loads the page content from BitBucket fine so I would be very surprised if there are any race conditions at play here.Likewise,I am doubtful caching is the problem.

Comment: So it seems this does not have anything to do with gatsby? If so, it's probably best to remove the gatsby tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ksav unfortunately,removing Gatsby is not an option.It is a requirement for the front-end.

Comment: I was referring to the gatsby tag on this question.

Comment: @ksav sorry,I misread your comment.The Kaldi template comes with Netlify CMS kind of baked in so I'm not completely sure it isn't something in the Gatsby code that is causing the problem on the Netlify side.I am new to the JAM stack and the front and backend seem less decoupled than with something like MEAN or MERN.